# How to search for a flight with no bags or no includedCheckedBags in amadeus?

Tags: amadeus

When trying to hit search api with `includedCheckedBagsOnly:false`
or
When trying to hit price api by removing `includedCheckedBags:{quantity: 2}` object or making quantity to 0

Pricing returns with `includedCheckedBags:{quantity: 2}`

Is it possible to book a flight with no bags at all ?

**I get this response for pricing (with bags) but need without any bags**

```
"pricingOptions": {
                    "fareType": [
                        "PUBLISHED"
                    ],
                    "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
                },
"travelerPricings": [
                    {
                        "travelerId": "1",
                        "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                        "travelerType": "ADULT",
                        "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                            {
                                "segmentId": "3",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "N3PRONG",
                                "class": "N",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 2
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "segmentId": "4",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "N3PRONG",
                                "class": "N",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 2
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "segmentId": "159",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "N3PRONG",
                                "class": "N",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 2
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "segmentId": "160",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "N3PRONG",
                                "class": "N",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 2
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: have you found a solution bahi?

Comment: I doubt that there is an option to exclude all checked bags. perhaps you can filter out from the response?